# Версия PHP в терминале отличается от phpinfo

Tags: php, mac, terminal

На macOS High Sierra был установлен PHP 7.1.7. Через Brew установил PHP 7.2.

При выводе данных через `phpinfo()` показывает версию 7.1.7, но в терминале через `php -v` показывает 7.2

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php

/usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 17:34:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

$ whereis php
/usr/bin/php

$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Кто знает, как мне указать последную версию? Чтобы везде было всё одинаково.

Спасибо

Comment: Что такое «везде было все одинаково»?

Comment: Вы в терминале смотрите версию в папке, где лежит `php`, в частности тут `/usr/local/bin/php` существует файл php, поэтому Вам отдается 7.2 . Версия, которой происходит обработка по дефолту - та, которая показана в `phpinfo();`